# Copy same file to multiple destinations

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, copy-item

I want to copy a file to multiple destinations using a script that filters through a directory and selects the newest file in the $File_path then change its name and copies it to the $destination, the script i'm using is this:

```
 $File_path = "C:\TEMP\export\liste\Text_Utf8\"
 $destination = "C:\TEMP\export\C7E001"
get-childitem -path $File_path -Filter "Ges?*.txt" | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
    select-object -last 1  | copy-item -Destination (join-path $destination "FRER3000CCFETES01_IN.DEV")
```

this only copies it to one location, is there a way to improve it to copy the same file to multiple locations? i have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679868/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-folders-in-powershell) but it seems different.

the other locations are as follow:

C:\TEMP\export\C7P001
C:\TEMP\export\C7F001
C:\TEMP\export\C7S001
and so on.

thank you.

Comment: But where are your 'multiple destinations'? All we see is you copy a file to a single destination `C:\TEMP\export\C7E001`

Comment: These are my other destenations: C:\TEMP\export\C7P001 C:\TEMP\export\C7F001 C:\TEMP\export\C7S001, how to implement them in the script is what i need help with, i have tried making an array of folders, then iterates through each one but it didn't work because i didn't manage to implement it so that the selection of the newest file and renaiming it still works.

Comment: If you want the latest file, then better use `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreationTime`

Comment: Thank you @Theo, i will try that, i am interested in seeing your solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my answer isn't very different to [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098466/9898643), This uses the `LastWriteTime` property to get the latest file and uses the `FullName` property of the file to copy in the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
$File_path    = "C:\TEMP\export\liste\Text_Utf8"
$destinations = "C:\TEMP\export\C7E001", "C:\TEMP\export\C7F001", "C:\TEMP\export\C7S001"
$fileToCopy   = Get-ChildItem -Path $File_path -Filter "Ges*.txt" -File | 
                Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime | 
                Select-Object -Last 1

foreach ($dest in $destinations) {
    Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy.FullName -Destination (Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath "FRER3000CCFETES01_IN.DEV")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an foreach object loop

```
$File_path = "C:\TEMP\export\liste\Text_Utf8\"
$destination = "C:\TEMP\export\C7E001", "C:\TEMP\export\C7P001", "C:\TEMP\export\C7F001", "C:\TEMP\export\C7S001"
$Files = get-childitem -path $File_path -Filter "Ges?*.txt" | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
    select-object -last 1 
$Destination | Foreach-Object {copy-item $Files -Destination (join-path $_ "FRER3000CCFETES01_IN.DEV")}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have tried that rn, it is showing me an error that in this line `{copy-item $Files -Destination (join-path $_ "FRER3000CCFETES01_IN.DEV")}` the path **G:\Ges0888_Utf8.TXT**does not exist! where did we use this path?